# Why does the domain of $\frac{1}{\;\frac{1}{\cos(x)}\;}$ differ from that of $\frac{1}{\sec(x)}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

So I've found out that 2 **equivalent** functions have **different** domains, and I want to know why:
$$\frac{1}{\;\frac{1}{\cos(x)}\;} \qquad\text{and}\qquad\frac{1}{\sec(x)}$$ are equivalent BUT their domain's are different,

The domain of $1/\sec(x)$ is $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{\pi/2+k\pi\}$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, while the domain of $1/(1/\cos(x))$ is all reals.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rational functions may have equivalent expressions, but the domain may differ depending on how they are written. For example, consider

$$\frac{x(x+2)}{x+2} = x.$$

According to the expression on the left, there is a hole in the domain at $x = -2$, while on the right the domain is all real numbers. The equality holds for all $x \neq -2$.

Your example is analogous.

Comment: Yes in other words, $\frac{x(x+2)}{x+2}$ is undefined for $x=-2$, whereas $x$ is defined for $x=-2$.

Comment: Adam Rubinson, that is true but is the opposite of what bounceback said, which is wrong!

Comment: Whoops, I somehow manage to get this basic thing wrong very often. I hope the analogy is useful, however. Thanks for the feedback, and please allow me to edit.

Answer (score 3):

You are incorrect about the domain of $$\frac{1}{\quad\frac{1}{\cos x}\quad}.$$

Recall that when we describe a function, we are supposed to give the domain and the value at every point of the domain. We have a *convention* that, for real-valued functions of real variable, **if** we describe a function by giving a formula **and** we do not explicitly state the domain, then the domain is “all numbers for which the formula, *as written*, makes sense.” This is called the “natural domain of the function.”

The function
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\quad\frac{1}{\cos x}\quad}$$
is given just by a formula. So the domain is “all $x$ for which the formula, as written, makes sense”.

The $\cos(x)$ part always makes sense. The reciprocal only makes sense when $\cos(x)\neq 0$, so we must exclude all $x$ at which $\cos(x)=0$; this is all $x$ of the form $x=\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n$, with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, or of the form $\frac{3\pi}{2}+2\pi n$, with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. These two amount to all reals except those of the form $\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then the reciprocal of *that* will make sense provided $\frac{1}{\cos(x)}\neq 0$. As this always happens, that is all.

So the natural domain of $f(x)$ is all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ except for those reals of the form $\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$... exactly the same domain as the function $g(x)=\frac{1}{\sec x}$. So the two are in fact the same function, as they have the same domain and always take the same values.

By contrast, consider $\tan(x) = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$, $\cot(x) = \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$. If we let $f(x) = \frac{1}{\cot x}$, is this function equal to $\tan (x)$?

No! Because $\tan(x)$ is defined at all points where $\cos(x)\neq 0$, which means all $x$ except those of the form $\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ (like the previous function).

The domain of $f(x)$ is all $x$, except those for which *either* $\cot(x)$ is undefined, or those in which $\cot(x)=0$. This means both all points of the form $\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ (points where $\cot(x)=0$), *and* all points of the form $n\pi$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ (where $\cot(x)$ is undefined). So we get that the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{\cot(x)}$ has domain all real numbers except those of the form $\frac{k\pi}{2}$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, whereas $\tan(x)$ is defined at all $x$ except those of the form $\frac{\pi}{2}+m\pi$, $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

The moral here is that to find the natural domain of a function you *do not simplify*, as that may change the domain of the function.